# Креш Visual Studio 2013 в WinForms

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

Итак, что имеем. Windows 8.1 x64 + Visual Studio 2013 Up4.

Суть проблемы в том, что практический любой проект в WinForms при открытии - валит студию. Те, которые не валит - работать невозможно. Мышь дёргается (мигает курсор), в пропертибар попасть - большая удача. Контролы не ресайзятся, не переносятся. 90% форм при открытии валят студию.

Такая ситуация повторяется на разных машинах с Win7\Win8\Win8.1 со студией 2013.

Что известно:

**1**) Проблема в контролах, в которых присутствует такой элемент:

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Любой другой контрол, в котором нет данной "стрелочки" - работает нормально, полноценно: т.е. кнопки, лейблы, радиобатоны и прочее. Ставишь текстовое поле - вот эта стрелка начинает неистово дёргаться. Такое впечатление, что идёт постоянная отрисовка окна - мерцания, мигания; При этом чтобы попасть в пропертибар - F4 не помогает и приходится "выкручиваться" поиском нужного контрола в списке пропертибара, что очень дико раздражает.

**2**) Студия "чистая" - все решарперы, всё посносил. В ASP.NET и других типах проектов всё работает прекрасно. Только в WinForms ошибка. Да и то, если не открывать формы - можно работать :D Всё компилится и летает, пока форму не открываешь..

Что помогает:
Под админом в консоли сделать:

```
netsh winsock reset
```

Почему именно **WinSock** Reset помогает - большая загадка. Спрашивал и на en.stackoverflow и где ещё только угодно. Возможно, что не хватало "английского" для более детального описания, не знаю. Так вот данная команда помогает обязательно с перезагрузкой и на день. Т.е. ввёл, перезагрузился - день студия работает. Перезагрузился ещё раз - всё. Работать можно, конечно, но это какие-то страдания)..

Что выяснено:

1. `Tools\Import + Export\Reset all settings` - не помогает;
2. Переустановка OS помогает только на некоторое время;
3. Переустановка VS: исправление и\или полное удаление + установка - не помогает;

**4**. Снёс всё, что только видел лишнего в студии: решарперы, рефлектор и прочее; Остались только официальные апдейты + официальные всякие SDK, аля WinPhone; Ничего стороннего. Во всяком случае ни в экстеншинах ничего "подозрительного" не вижу.

**5**. При аттаче из другого экземпляра к студии с проектом вываливается, как правило два эксепшина:

первый (при добавлении, скажем, StatusStrip), чаще всего:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Drawing.dll Additional information: Object is
>   currently in use elsewhere.

второй, редко (при том, что с памятью всё ок - мемтест и полный прогон по оперативе дал 100% работающий результат + нигде никаких проблем помимо студии не возникало; хотя я работаю с не самым скромным до ресурсов софтом):

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred > in System.Drawing.dll
>   Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Я ~10 лет уже работаю с C#, VB.NET, начиная с 2003 студии. Все проблема касательно кода предпочитаю решать сам, а тут вылезло ЭТО ВСЁ и куда копать дальше - ума не приложу. Возможно, что глаз замылился. Возможно, что не там ищу.

**P.S.**: Если надо будет, я могу заснять "поведение" WinForms Designer'а. Если это хоть как-то поможет.

Comment: я еще заметил, когда закрываешь студио закрывается долго, когда валится... закрывается так быстро, что даже сомниваешьсня открыл ли ты вообще?

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan, У вас установлены какие-нибудь плагины для VS?

Comment: Креши студии (и вообще любые проблемы с ней) стоит репортить на официальный багрекер - [connect.microsoft.com](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/). Кроме того, студию можно отладить (другой студией или windbg) и поискать намеки в стектрейсе или в самом исключении. Тут вам особо ничем не помогут.

Comment: Есть какие-то новости? Возможно, проблема уйдёт, если накатить свежий апдейт Visual Studio.

Comment: Похоже на проблемы с драйверами видеокарты.

Comment: Тему закрыли по причине: "Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы.". Не знаю как ещё подробнее, гг ))

Comment: @GRUNGER вы пробовали отладить студию (как я вам выше предложил?) и посмотреть хотя бы стектрейс. или просто гг при каждом креше?

Comment: @GRUNGER вы обратились в connect? попытались локализовать проблему? формально, это просьба помочь с отладкой невоспроизводимой проблемы. причем чужого кода. причем продукта, у которого есть хороший официальный саппорт. какой помощи вы ждете на SO? магической фразы "поменяй в реестре ключ ZZZ" - ее не будет. если вы не запостили баг в connect - значит вы не хотите решить проблему. а раз она воспроизводится только у вас, и лично вас не напрягает - то и проблемы, собственно, нет

Comment: @GRUNGER: Не [это](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/819552/visual-studio-debugger-throws-accessviolationexception) ли ваша проблема? Попробуйте обновиться до 4.5.2.

Comment: @PashaPash http://prntscr.com/9a7h41 надеюсь, вам эта единичка пригодилась и принесла радости :)

ЗЫ со студией проблема ушла только после миграции на Win10. На Win8.1 решить не удалось никакими средствами. Возможно, действительно, железно. А, возможно, виною всему злодей, имя которого произносить нельзя.. )

Comment: Ну ненадо так кричать на человека :) С WinForms - одна проблема - их несуществует. Те оставили интерфейсы для совместимости древнего софта и все. Сейчас интерфейс построен на wpf полностью (и это уже лет 5 или больше как) - именно с тех пор как майкрософт убрал все вопросы по винформам из сертификационных тестов. Поэтому как будет работать студия (2013) - уже староватая версия на операционке - которая тоже старовата, с технологией которая "в режиме совместимости" - трудно сказать :). Скачайте студию поновее - благо дело community editions бесплатные, и win 10  - там хоть bash есть :) :) :)

Comment: @Muritiku а вы, сударь, некропостер :) достали 3 летней давности пост)

Comment: @GRUNGER - он в поиске в топе :) Я же не специально его искал.

Comment: WinForms тем не менее актуальны по причине совместимости с `mono` и стабильной работой на разных платформах, в отличии от несовместимой ни с чем wpf.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что это просьба помочь с отладкой невоспроизводимой ошибки.

Comment: Перейди на более новые версии там такой баг пофиксен